# DrawText Randomly doesn't include spaces(printer)

Tags: c++, winapi, printing, xps

Heres the code:

```
HRESULT DisplayPrintPropertySheet(HWND hWnd)
{
HRESULT hResult;
PRINTDLGEX pdx = {0};
LPPRINTPAGERANGE pPageRanges = NULL;
DWORD dwBytesWritten = 0L;



// Allocate an array of PRINTPAGERANGE structures.
pPageRanges = (LPPRINTPAGERANGE) GlobalAlloc(GPTR, 10 * sizeof(PRINTPAGERANGE));
if (!pPageRanges)
    return E_OUTOFMEMORY;

//  Initialize the PRINTDLGEX structure.
pdx.lStructSize = sizeof(PRINTDLGEX);
pdx.hwndOwner = hWnd;
pdx.hDevMode = NULL;
pdx.hDevNames = NULL;
pdx.hDC = NULL;
pdx.Flags = PD_RETURNDC | PD_COLLATE;
pdx.Flags2 = 0;
pdx.ExclusionFlags = 0;
pdx.nPageRanges = 0;
pdx.nMaxPageRanges = 10;
pdx.lpPageRanges = pPageRanges;
pdx.nMinPage = 1;
pdx.nMaxPage = 1000;
pdx.nCopies = 1;
pdx.hInstance = 0;
pdx.lpPrintTemplateName = NULL;
pdx.lpCallback = NULL;
pdx.nPropertyPages = 0;
pdx.lphPropertyPages = NULL;
pdx.nStartPage = START_PAGE_GENERAL;
pdx.dwResultAction = 0;

//  Invoke the Print property sheet.

hResult = PrintDlgEx(&pdx);

if ((hResult == S_OK) && pdx.dwResultAction == PD_RESULT_PRINT)
{ //2976 // 3876 //210 //273

    cout << "HORZRES: " << GetDeviceCaps(pdx.hDC,PHYSICALWIDTH)/GetDeviceCaps(pdx.hDC,LOGPIXELSX) << endl;
    cout << "VERTRES : " <<GetDeviceCaps(pdx.hDC,PHYSICALHEIGHT)/GetDeviceCaps(pdx.hDC,LOGPIXELSY) << endl;
   DOCINFO di = {0};
 di.cbSize = sizeof(DOCINFO);
 di.lpszDocName = _T("Scribble Printout");
 di.lpszOutput = (LPTSTR) NULL;
 di.lpszDatatype = "RAW";
 di.fwType = 0;

 StartDoc(pdx.hDC, &di);

  StartPage(pdx.hDC);``
etMapMode(pdx.hDC, MM_HIENGLISH);
RECT rc;
rc.top = -1000;
rc.left = 500;
rc.right = 8000;
rc.bottom = -11000;

DrawText(pdx.hDC,"Legal Action Was Threatened",-1,&rc,DT_WORDBREAK);
   EndPage(pdx.hDC);


   EndDoc(pdx.hDC);
}


if (pdx.hDevMode != NULL)
    GlobalFree(pdx.hDevMode);
if (pdx.hDevNames != NULL)
    GlobalFree(pdx.hDevNames);
if (pdx.lpPageRanges != NULL)
    GlobalFree(pPageRanges);

if (pdx.hDC != NULL)
    DeleteDC(pdx.hDC);

return hResult;
}
```

The problem seems to be with DrawText.

This is what it's displaying via .xps:

---

[image]

Comment: Please trim the unnecessary whitespace from the bottom of those images.

Comment: What difference does it make?

Comment: It makes the question easier to parse without scrolling. And it helps to demonstrate that you are not lazy.

Comment: Did my best, it seem to add that whitespace whenever i upload the image though.

Comment: Any idea on the actual question? :P

Comment: Have you considered that the problem may be the .xps viewer?

Comment: Ive used my actual printer and came across the same error.